CONNECT_BY_ROOT Inside of a CONNECT_BY_ROOT
I'm trying to combine two CONNECT_BY_ROOT queries. They work well individually. I've been trying to combine them such that one is a subquery inside the other, but I'm falling short.
Query 1 - Replacing Part
In the Item Master table there's a column 'Replacing Part'. When an item has been replaced this column has the new part number. I'm using CONNECT_BY_ROOT to return the last (most recent) replacing part.
Sample Item Master data



c_id
part_id
replacing_part




101
cowl 1
cowl 2


102
cowl 2
cowl 3


103
cowl 3
cowl 4


104
cowl 4
null



SELECT DISTINCT
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.c_id child_CID,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_id child_PN,
d.c_id replacing_CID,
d.part_id replacing_PN,
level lvl
FROM Item_Master d
WHERE
d.cur_flag = 'y'
AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR d.replacing_part = d.part_id
START WITH d.c_id = 101

Result



child_CID
child_PN
replacing_CID
replacing_PN
lvl




101
cowl 1
104
cowl 4
4



Query 2 - Top Level Parent
I'm using CONNECT_BY_ROOT to find the top-level parent of each part. Here's the complication: when parts are replaced the association to parent assemblies is severed, they're orphan parts that no longer have a structure. That means CONNECT_BY_ROOT won't find the top-level parent.
SELECT DISTINCT
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.c_id child_CID,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_ID child_PN,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_name_eng child_name,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.cur_flag child_cur_flag,
d2.part_ID top_parent_PN,
d2.cur_flag top_par_cur_flag
FROM Structure_Master s
INNER JOIN Item_Master d on d.c_id = s.c_id_2
INNER JOIN Item_Master d2 on d2.c_id = s.c_id_1
WHERE
d2.opp_unit is not null --This filter removes everything but the "top-level" part
AND CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.cur_flag = 'y'
AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR s.c_id_1 = s.c_id_2
START WITH d.c_id = 104 --If this part is replaced the query won't return the top parent

Result



child_CID
child_PN
child_name
child_cur_flag
top_parent_PN
top_par_cur_flag




104
cowl 4
cowl weldment 4
y
big truck a1
y


104
cowl 4
cowl weldment 4
y
big truck b1
y



Combining queries
The data I'm analyzing has many parts that were replaced. I still need to see what top level assembly they used to belong to which is why I want to make the replacing part query a subquery of query 2. Here's my attempt to combine them. The issue I'm having is it's not returning anything. It takes half a second to run and returns nothing.
SELECT DISTINCT
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.c_id child_CID,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_ID child_PN,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_name_eng child_name,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.cur_flag child_cur_flag,
d2.part_ID top_parent_PN,
d2.cur_flag top_par_cur_flag
FROM Structure_Master s
INNER JOIN Item_Master d on d.c_id = s.c_id_2
INNER JOIN Item_Master d2 on d2.c_id = s.c_id_1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.c_id child_CID,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_id child_PN,
    d.c_id replacing_CID,
    d.part_id replacing_PN,
    level lvl
    FROM Item_Master d
    WHERE
    d.cur_flag = 'y'
    AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
    CONNECT BY PRIOR d.replacing_part = d.part_id
    START WITH d.c_id = 101
) r1 on r1.replacing_CID = s.c_id_2
WHERE
d2.NMH_OPP_BR_UNIT is not null
AND CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.CUR_FLAG = 'y'
AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR s.c_id_1 = s.c_id_2
START WITH d.c_id = r1.replacing_CID

I'm hoping it's a syntax issue or something small I'm screwing up. If pushed I'll try to supply a minimum reproduceable example, but that would take some time.
Thx for reading!

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements (that we can copy/paste and execute) for your sample data for all the tables you are using (and all the relevant columns); an English (not code) explanation of the problem; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment you have only provided data for one table and that is missing some columns and we don't know what a "correct" answer looks like so your question is difficult (impossible?) to answer.

@MT0 can you look at the code and see if there's a syntax error? Maybe with how I'm joining the subquery?

I cannot run the code without tables to run it against and I don't understand what you are trying to achieve because there is not sufficient explanation nor details of the expected output so, no, just looking at the code won't magically explain what "correct" logic or output looks like.

fiddle might help you.

I'm skeptical about that @MT0. You helped me with a question a few months ago, I took the time to create a minimum reproducible example, and your solution was I forgot to include CONNECT_BY_ISLEAK = 1. I appreciate the help though. I'll try to come up with an example.

"when parts are replaced the association to parent assemblies is severed, they're orphan parts that no longer have a structure." Your sample data does not have any orphaned parts - you need to provide a [MRE] that does. Additionally, if you have orphaned parts then, by definition, the link to the previous top-level parent has been broken so it may be impossible to find the previous top-level part as there is now zero relationship to it - if there is still a relationship to a top-level part then it is not an orphan - so what you are asking may be physically impossible; again a [MRE] is needed.

Your second and third queries use the Structure_Master table and there are no details of what that table contains. Again, a [MRE] is needed with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for some sample data.

I found a solution to my question. I waited to give others a chance to answer. I moved the subquery to the START WITH clause. I commented out the fields I didn't need to make it easier to troubleshoot and for me to remember what the subquery is doing.
This works but it wasn't the solution I imagined when I started. I didn't know you could put a subquery in the START WITH clause.
SELECT DISTINCT
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.c_id child_CID,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_ID child_PN,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_name_eng child_name,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.cur_flag child_cur_flag,
d2.part_ID top_parent_PN,
d2.cur_flag top_par_cur_flag
FROM Structure_Master s
INNER JOIN Item_Master d on d.c_id = s.c_id_2
INNER JOIN Item_Master d2 on d2.c_id = s.c_id_1
WHERE
d2.NMH_OPP_BR_UNIT is not null
AND CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.CUR_FLAG = 'y'
AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR s.c_id_1 = s.c_id_2
START WITH d.c_id =
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    --CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.c_id child_CID,
    --CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.part_id child_PN,
    d.c_id replacing_CID
    --, d.part_id replacing_PN,
    --level lvl
    FROM Item_Master d
    WHERE
    d.cur_flag = 'y'
    AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
    CONNECT BY PRIOR d.replacing_part = d.part_id
    START WITH d.c_id = 101
    )

